How to Enable DisplayPort on Ubuntu 24.04?
I’m using an HP EliteBook 840 G8 running Ubuntu 24.04 (Wayland, Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)), fully updated. When I connect my external monitor via an HDMI cable, it works flawlessly. However, when I use an HP USB-C Universal Dock and connect the external monitor to the dock with a DisplayPort cable, the monitor doesn’t detect any input. I’ve tried two different DisplayPort cables.
I’ve manually set the monitor’s input source to DisplayPort and also tested with Auto Detect, but neither works. Since my notebook lacks a DisplayPort port, I couldn’t test the setup without the docking station.
Notably, the docking station seems functional otherwise: the USB ports work, it charges the notebook, and the power LED is lit. I would appreciate any advice or troubleshooting suggestions to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Resolved: You need to install DisplayPort drivers for your dock. If HP doesn't provide them, use Snaptics's reference driver for Ubuntu:
https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
